# Javascript global object calls function?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope

I have a very odd problem with javascript. My code is rather long so here is an example of the structure and the problem:

```
var x = new function f() {
    this.id = "";
}

function g(obj) {
    if (x.id == "") {
        ...
        obj.firstChild.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript:o();");
        ...
        x.id = obj.id;
    } else if (x.id != obj.id) {
        ...
        x.id = "";
        g(obj);
    }
}

function o() {...
    if (something == something) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
        x.id = ""; // if-statement of the g() function is called here?
    }
}
```

As you can see, the if-statement of the g() function is for some reason called or re-run upon x.id being changed. I simply cannot understand this, because they are not in the same scope, and changing a variable should under no circumstances trigger anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something else is going on, not that statement affecting anything.  Look for setTimeouts, setIntervals, events, etc.  Put a breakpoint in your `g` function and check the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `x.id = ""; // if-statement of the g() function is called here?`

If the code really is as you show it, that line of code will not generate a function call. The line is simply an assignment to the `id` property of `x`. The only way a function call could be triggered by your assigning to the `id` property of `x` would be if you were using a browser that supported property accessors (getters and setters), which is very unlikely (and there's nothing in your code doing so).

Something else would appear to be calling `g` in a loop of some kind, and so your changing the value makes the next call to `g` see the change. As Jonathon pointed out in his comment on the question, this could be something you've set up with `setTimeout`, or `setInterval`, or in an even handler (on mouse move, for instance), etc., but it's nothing in the quoted code.

---

**Possibly off-topic:**

You have this line of code at the outset:

```
var x = new function f() {
    this.id = "";
}
```

That code uses a "named function expression," which *should* be valid but causes problems in some implemenations (IE, for instance). Split it up to get the desired result reliably cross-browser:

```
var x = new f();
function f() {
    this.id = "";
}
```

---

**Off-topic**:

You don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol except on attributes that take a URI (like `href` on `a` elements). The `onclick` attribute does not take a URI, it takes JavaScript code, so change:

```
obj.firstChild.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript:o();");
```

to

```
obj.firstChild.setAttribute("onclick", "o();");
```

**But**, better yet, assign the handler directly:

```
obj.firstChild.onclick = o;
```

...or even consider using `addEventListener` or its IE-counterpart `attachEvent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. I have now figured out the problem. The function g() is called whenever a certain tableRow object is clicked. This same tableRow contains the obj.firstChild. Because of this, when i click on obj.firstChild, both o() and g() is executed.

Now i have got to figure out how i can prevent g() from being called when obj.firsChild is clicked.